# Paging data with HQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pagination, hql

I have a java web application where I use `Hibernate` and `MySQL`.
On a page I have a search form where on submit i create a HQL `Query` to fetch the results.

I used `.setFirstResult()` and `.setMaxResults()` for paging. This works fine, but not when my resultset contains alot of records... 
I thought .setMaxResults() would use limit in the actual SQL query, but it appears it doesn't.
So it loads the whole result in memory, and only then uses the value I set in .setMaxResults(), which results in memory problems.

Is this how it works, or am I just doing something wrong?

If so this is just not usable for me.

**ps:**
With Criteria API it does work, but there I had some other limitations on creating the criteria. Thats why I tried to use HQL instead, but I'm now facing this problem.

So am I right in my observations? Is there another solution?

Comment: Could this be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348143/hibernate-hql-pagination?